# Idiom for data aggregation and post processing in C++

Tags: c++

A common task in programming is to process data on the fly and, when all data are collected, do some post processing. A simple example for this would be the computation of the average (and other statistics), where you can have a class like this

```
class Statistic {
public:
  Statistic() : nr(0), sum(0.0), avg(0.0) {}

  void add(double x) { sum += x; ++nr; }
  void process() { avg = sum / nr; }

private:
  int nr;
  double sum;
  double avg;
};
```

A disadvantage with this approach is, that we always have to remember to call the `process()` function after adding all the data. Since in C++ we have things like RAII, this seems like a less than ideal solution.

In Ruby, for example, we can write code like this

```
class Avg
  attr_reader :avg

  def initialize
    @nr = 0
    @sum = 0.0
    @avg = nil
    if block_given?
      yield self
      process
    end
  end

  def add(x)
    @nr += 1
    @sum += x.to_f
  end

  def process
    @avg = @sum / @nr
  end
end
```

which we then can call like this

```
avg = Avg.new do |a|
  data.each {|x| a.add(x)}
end
```

and the `process` method is automatically called when exiting the block.

Is there an idiom in C++ that can provide something similar?

For clarification: this question is not about computing the average. It is about the following pattern: feeding data to an object and then, when all the data is fed, triggering a processing step. I am interested in context-based ways to automatically trigger the processing step - or reasons why this would not be a good idea in C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"Idiomatic average"**

I don't know Ruby but you can't translate idioms directly anyhow. I know that calculating the average is just an example, so lets see what we can get from that example...

Idiomatic way to caclulate sum, and average of elements in a container is `std::accumulate`:

```
std::vector<double> data;
// ... fill data ...
auto sum = std::accumulate( a.begin(), a.end() , 0.0);
auto avg = sum / a.size();
```

The building blocks are container, iterator and algorithms.

If you do not have elements to be processed readily available in a container you can still use the same algorithms, because algorithms only care about iterators. Writing your own iterators requires a bit of boilerplate. The following is just a toy example that calcualtes average of results of calling the same function a certain number of times:

```
#include <numeric>

template <typename F>
struct my_iter {
    F f;
    size_t count;
    my_iter(size_t count, F f) : count(count),f(f) {}
    my_iter& operator++() {
        --count;
        return *this;
    }
    auto operator*() { return f(); }
    bool operator==(const my_iter& other) const { return count == other.count;}
};


int main()
{
    auto f = [](){return 1.;};
    auto begin = my_iter{5,f};
    auto end = my_iter{0,f};
    auto sum = std::accumulate( begin, end, 0.0);
    auto avg = sum / 5;
    std::cout << sum << " " << avg;
}
```

Output is:

```
5 1
```

Suppose you have a vector of paramters for a function to be called, then calling `std::accumulate` is straight-forward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    auto f = [](int x){return x;};
    std::vector<int> v = {1,2,5,10};
    
    auto sum = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0, [f](int accu,int add) {
        return accu + f(add);
    });
    auto avg = sum / 5;
    std::cout << sum << " " << avg;
}
```

The last argument to `std::accumulate` specifies how the elements are added up. Instead of adding them up directly I add up the result of calling the function. Output is:

```
18 3.6
```

**For your actual question**

Taking your question more literally and to answer also the RAII part, here is one way you can make use of RAII with your statistic class:

```
struct StatisticCollector {
private:
    Statistic& s;
public:
    StatisticCollector(Statistic& s) : s(s) {}
    ~StatisticCollector() { s.process(); }
};

int main()
{
    Statistic stat;
    {
        StatisticCollector sc{stat};
        //for (...)
        // stat.add( x );
    } // <- destructor is called here

}
```

*PS:* Last but not least there is the alternative to just keep it simple. Your class definition is kinda broken, because all results are private. Once you fix that, it is kinda obvious that you need no RAII to make sure `process` gets called:

```
class Statistic {
public:
  Statistic() : nr(0), sum(0.0), avg(0.0) {}

  void add(double x) { sum += x; ++nr; }
  double process() { return sum / nr; }
private:
  int nr;
  double sum;
};
```

This is the right interface in my opinion. The user cannot forget to call `process` because to get the result they need to call it. If the only purpose of the class is to accumulate numbers and process the result it should not encapsulate the result. The result is for the user of the class to store.

Comment: Kind of by definition you can't translate idioms directly - there's no reason to suppose something that is "idiomatic" in one computer language is also idiomatic in another.  Applies to human languages as well, of course ...  And yes - either just use a scope guard (RAII) or use std::accumulate.  I myself like std::accumulate, which is a functional  programming idiom (fold) successfully brought to c++ (though with added syntax cruft relative to true functional languages) but some don't ...

Comment: @davidbak frankly, it was just the polite way of saying "I dont know Ruby and I will ignore that part because it isnt really relevant". Averaging some values is a nice example to overthink, though given OPs code I would simply go for what I wrote in the PPS and leave it be

Comment: @idclev463035818 you seem to be too much focused on the average in this answer. It was used by me as the simplest example of the following pattern: an object gets fed data and then, when all data has been fed, a processing step is triggered. This question is about a context based triggering of the processing step, comparable to the automatic freeing of resources in RAII.

Comment: ... however your PS is actually a good answer to the question. I would suggest to edit the answer and cut away everything else.

Comment: I think the PPS is the right answer.   If process() is called automatically to calculate some data and store it so that later a function can be called to retrieve the stored data then why are we storing it in the first place?  Especially when calling process manually could calculate the data on the fly and return it directly without storing it.  If you are going to retrieve the data then calculate it when you need it - don't waste time calculating it unless you need it.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah  more often than not the process step will be very expensive computation. So, the solution as it stands is not suitable for that kind of task. However, I see how the example can be modified to accommodate such cases - but it would come with its own set of disadvantages (when querying the answer might not be the time when you want to incur the computation cost; extensive use of mutables in your class).

Comment: @Eigentime calculating the average is just the example. I showed you how to calculate it when you have a) all data readily available in a container b) you collect all during the calculation c) you have a container that you need to transform to get the data d) your approach with RAII e) your approach without RAII. Replace "calculate average" with something else any you still have similar alternatives. You will still use the same building blocks. I didn't go into concurrency because I had to stop somewhere ;)

Comment: @Eigentime if you want you can for example wrap the second option (use iterators to retrieve the input) into an object to get what you asked for

Comment: @idclev463035818 I am sorry if I was not clear enough so far. But everything up to your PS does not answer the question I thought I was asking. The whole accumulate part is not relevant - it is just an elegant way of putting the data into your object - but it is not what I am asking. This question is about the processing step afterwards and the options of calling it - preferably in an automated way.

Comment: @Eigentime partly yes, I knew that I didn't understand what the actual question is when writing this answer. Partly no, because imho your approach is already flawed and I felt like explaining that in length. The "processing step afterwards" is jsut calling a function (an algorithm) that yields the result. As I don't  really see where RAII fits in I had to show how I would do it instead.

Comment: @Eigentime in any case, I still think the answer as it stands is fine. Glad when you got anything from it

Comment: @Eigentime I change the headers, hope that adresses your critique